# Why does Resharper flag this class member?

Tags: c#, variables, boolean, resharper

The "DeviceInCradle" here is grayed out:

```
private bool DeviceInCradle = false;
```

Thinking maybe it was an unused var, I commented it out, but then got, "The name 'DeviceInCradle' does not exist in the class or namespace 'Duckbill.Platypus'"

I could grok the grayification of "= false," as that's what a bool is by default, but why would it grayify the name of the var this way?

Comment: If you're using Resharper, it should tell you why it's graying it out. Just by looking, it might be because of your naming. Private fields should be camelCased, not PascalCased.

Comment: Elsewhere you comment **Actually, hovering over it gave me: "DeviceInCradle is only assigned but its value is never used"** - is that not the answer to your question??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might also be that the variable isn't used anywhere. ReSharper will gray out an unused private variable. Or a variable that's set but never referenced.

Answer (score 5):

Resharper wants private field names to be camelCased, not PascalCased. For example, both of these should be a-ok to Resharper:

```
private bool deviceInCradle = false;
```

Or

```
private bool _deviceInCradle = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you hover over it, it should tell you:

```
Name 'DeviceInCradle' does not match rule 'InstanceField(private)'. Suggested name is '_deviceInCradle'.
```

In other words, its name doesn't match Resharper's default naming conventions.

Comment: Actually, hovering over it gave me: "DeviceInCradle is only assigned but its value is never used"